# Can't seem to find this database connection leak

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc, c3p0

I'm working on a project for class parsing a file and then inserting the parsed data into a database. Because the number of records numbers in the millions, I decided to do it multithreaded using an executor service and c3p0 for database connection pooling. However, somewhere along the way there seems to be a database connection leak and I cannot figure out where, but when I run show full processlist on the database, it shows all the connections as sleeping. Specifically, I believe this leak is occurring in the person section of the run method, because I get all of the publications in fine and when I commented that section out the whole thing ran through without fail. Usually around 200,000 entries into the processing the persons is when the leak occurs. Here's my threads' run method:

```
protected Connection DB;
private ComboPooledDataSource source;
protected static final Object lock = new Object();

public void openDB() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            this.DB = source.getConnection();
            this.DB.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            SynchronizedPrinter.printErr(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void closeDB() {
    try {
        if (!DB.isClosed()) {
            DB.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        SynchronizedPrinter.printErr(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
public static boolean executeBatches(PreparedStatement ps) {
    try {
        ps.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        String exm = ex.getMessage();
        if (exm.contains("try restarting transaction")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    this.openDB();
    SynchronizedPrinter.printOut(Thread.currentThread() + " open");

    try {
        boolean executePerson = !personList.isEmpty();
        while (executePerson) {
            ps_person = DB.prepareStatement(INSERT_PERSON);
            for (Element e : personList) {
                ps_person.setString(1, e.getKey());
                ps_person.setInt(2, getAuthorId(e.getFirstAuthor().getContent()));
                List<Field> insertList = e.getFieldListForInsert();
                for (int i = 0; i < insertList.size(); i++) {
                    ps_person.setString(i + 3, insertList.get(i) == null ? null : insertList.get(i).getContent());
                }
                ps_person.addBatch();
            }
            SynchronizedPrinter.printOut(Thread.currentThread() + " execute person");
            executePerson = executeBatches(ps_person);
            SynchronizedPrinter.printOut(Thread.currentThread() + " executed person");
            ps_person.close();
            if (executePerson) {
                DB.rollback();
            } else {
                DB.commit();
            }
            SynchronizedPrinter.printOut(Thread.currentThread() + " committed person");
        }

        boolean executeSynonym = !synonymList.isEmpty();
        while (executeSynonym) {
            ps_synonym = DB.prepareStatement(AUTHOR_SYNONYM_MAPPER);
            for (Element e : synonymList) {
                for (Field f : e.getAuthorList()) {
                    if (!f.equals(e.getFirstAuthor())) {
                        ps_synonym.setInt(1, getAuthorId(e.getFirstAuthor().getContent()));
                        ps_synonym.setString(2, f.getContent());
                        ps_synonym.addBatch();
                    }
                }
            }
            executeSynonym = executeBatches(ps_synonym);
            ps_synonym.close();
            if (executeSynonym) {
                DB.rollback();
            } else {
                DB.commit();
            }
        }

        boolean executePublication = !pubList.isEmpty();
        while (executePublication) {
            ps_pub = DB.prepareStatement(INSERT_PUB);
            for (Element e : pubList) {
                ps_pub.setString(1, e.getKey());
                ps_pub.setString(2, e.elementType.toString());
                List<Field> insertList = e.getFieldListForInsert();
                for (int i = 0; i < insertList.size(); i++) {
                    ps_pub.setString(i + 3, insertList.get(i) == null ? null : insertList.get(i).getContent());
                }
                ps_pub.addBatch();
            }
            executePublication = executeBatches(ps_pub);
            ps_pub.close();
            if (executePublication) {
                DB.rollback();
            } else {
                DB.commit();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        SynchronizedPrinter.printErr("Something terribly wrong has occurred:\n" + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    SynchronizedPrinter.printOut(Thread.currentThread() + " closing");
    this.closeDB();
    SynchronizedPrinter.printOut(Thread.currentThread() + " closed");
}
```

Here's the method that opens the thread. It passes the ComboPooledDataSource and the elements to be inserted (1024 elements at a time, which are then divided up based on whether they are publications, persons, or synonyms):

```
if (currentCounter >= PROCESSED_AT_ONCE) {
            try {
                while (source.getNumBusyConnections() >= CONNECTION_LIMIT-1) Thread.yield();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                SynchronizedPrinter.printErr(ex.getMessage());
            }
            service.submit(new ElementProcessor(source, currentElements));
            currentCounter = 0;
        }
```

Finally, here's some of the jstack dump I generated once all the threads were stuck. All the threads are stuck at the same spot it would seem:

```
"pool-1-thread-63" #79 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fa849439000 nid=0xdc03 waiting on condition [0x000070000599e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2c39588> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't figure out for the life of me what's causing this. The publication and synonym inserts work perfectly with no issue, yet the persons have been extremely problematic, always causing some sort of lock that I can never get past. Yet, the logic is almost entirely the same as the other two.

Here's the last couple lines from the output log I generated as well, where it starts to get erratic:

```
Thread[pool-1-thread-60,5,main] open
Thread[pool-1-thread-33,5,main] executed person
Thread[pool-1-thread-33,5,main] committed person
Thread[pool-1-thread-33,5,main] closing
Thread[pool-1-thread-33,5,main] closed
Thread[pool-1-thread-46,5,main] open
Thread[pool-1-thread-46,5,main] execute person
Thread[pool-1-thread-54,5,main] executed person
Thread[pool-1-thread-54,5,main] committed person
Thread[pool-1-thread-54,5,main] closing
Thread[pool-1-thread-54,5,main] closed
Thread[pool-1-thread-40,5,main] open
Thread[pool-1-thread-46,5,main] executed person
Thread[pool-1-thread-46,5,main] committed person
Thread[pool-1-thread-46,5,main] closing
Thread[pool-1-thread-46,5,main] closed
Thread[pool-1-thread-16,5,main] open
```

I'm really lost as to what's causing all of this and any help anybody could offer would be amazing.

Comment: You've omitted the most important part, showing where and how connections are acquired.  We don't have enough information to help you.  Also, you're violating some basic design principles in having your thread close the db connection but not acquire it.  You should be using try-with-resources everywhere and avoid all the complex logic in your catch clauses.

Comment: I added the connection acquisition. The reason I've done it this way is to have each thread clean up its own connection when it is done.

Comment: That's fine, but the thread should also acquire the connection from the pool. Acquiring a resource in one place and freeing it somewhere else is a asking for trouble, as you have seen.

Comment: Hey, I changed a bunch of stuff and added a lot more detail. Do you think you could take another look at it?